# Testing LDAP Authentication in a laptop with out a Domain

Tags: asp.net, ldap

I have to develop a ASP.net application and need to authenticate users using LDAP. 
I don't have a windows server installed .  I wonder how I can test my code from my local laptop

Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install `Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS`) It has almost the same features that an AD server. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897400.aspx

It's quite easy to install it. You can download it for windows 7 or it's already in windows 8, you just have to turn the feature on from "Program and Features".

Then you can manage the ad instance using a tool called `ADSI Edit`, and for aspnet authentication just the `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`.

Comment: Thanks Esteban Elverdin